# How to support multi-lingual email in AWS Forgot Password scenario

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, forgot-password

I am using AWS Cognito to manage my users and would like to control the phrasing of the email that is sent to the user in the "Forgot Password" flow.

I am basing my solution on this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html

Basically, AWS lets you define a Lambda function that would get invoked when the email needs to be sent and lets you define the content of the email's subject and body (injecting the verification code into the body).

My question is this:
The user can be using the application in one of many languages. This means that a German user could view the application in German.
When he initiates the "Forgot Password" flow, he should get the email in German.
However, the Lambda function cannot know anything about the user because he is logged out when this flow happens and so Cognito cannot pass this information.

How can this be solved?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just retrieve the user data based on the email address in the custom message lambda?

Comment: This is indeed what I am going to do. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to somehow extract that information about a user. Cognito will not help you in this case because, as you have stated, the user is not authenticated.

Other option that you have is to assume that the user's language is the same as the language that is used in the place where the request originated from (let's say via sender's IP). But this is very unreliable solution.

Another option is to create a DynamoDB table (or to use any other DB solution, but DynamoDB is the most suitable one for this task) and store user's email and language of that user there. Then, if you invoke lambda function, you already have email address of the user passed to it and you can use it to fetch the corresponding language from DynamoDB before you generate the reset password email.

Comment: I like the database solution.
Thanks